# How to send a command to SQL Server complete a batch started from a select query sent by a VB.Net program?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I'm trying to execute a select query (with joins) and when there are a small number of records to return, I can see in SQL Server Profiler the following EventClass:
SQL:BatchStarting and after that SQL:BatchCompleted.
I'm using the ExecuteReader from ADO.NET.
So far, so good, I can use the information and make some inserts in the same table I retrieved the information in the select query.

But when the select query returns more rows (I can't specify how much, but I believe it is irrelevant) the SQL Server Profiler doesn't show the SQL:BatchCompleted event and the insert I need to do can't run because the batch is still running.

How do I send a command to execute and return all the rows and then complete the batch.

I'm using VB.NET but I believe C# answers can help me too.

Comment: If you are trying to use the same connection for the insert as the active SELECT query, you'll need to either use a different connection, use [Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets), or consume all the results before using the same connection for the insert like David mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The batch request is not complete until the client fetches the rows.

Al you need to call SqlDataReader.Read() for each row in the result and then SqlDataReader.Close(), or SqlDataReader.Dispose() to complete the batch request.